# Iterating over each pixel of an image in the time-series

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, analysis

I am using on GEE for a small analysis of Sentinel-1 data collection. I would like to go through each pixel of my AOI and check whether there was a drop in the time-series and classify that pixel accordingly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: what have you tried? do you have a code to share?

Comment: Dear @RodrigoE.Principe , Sure, this is the code I am using: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd87f6677020094f6f5c4fc1e99a19e5

Comment: I think you should update the post to include the code (the link at least)